# Java Index Array Out of Bounds Exception

Tags: java

This loop is strange.

I ran this in Java, it gives an Index out of bounds exception. I can't find an `int l` declaration anywhere in the source code and i can't figure out what it is and found out that it is legal for it to be declared this way.

But the deal here is, i don't understand what this piece of code is doing. For any size of `resultSIList`, it gives an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
for (int i = offset, l = Math.min(i + maxItemsInOnePage, totalSIs); i < l; i++){
    resultSIList.get(i);
}
```

**EDIT**: Thanks all.

Here is a runnable code i am using to try to understand this entire loop. Yes it is a horrible piece of junk.

```
public class IndexOutOfBoundsTest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int offset = 50;

        int maxItemsInOnePage = 50;

        int totalSIs = 50;

        final int buildThis = 15;

        List resultSIList = new ArrayList();

        // build list
        for(int zz = 0; zz < buildThis; zz ++){
            resultSIList.add("Hi " + zz);
        }

        try{
            for (int i = offset,
                    d = Math.min(i + maxItemsInOnePage, totalSIs);
                    i < d; i++){

               System.out.println(resultSIList.get(i));
           }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got one word for you: debugger.  Step through and see how the behavior fails to match your assumptions.

Comment: Could you have a negative `offset`?

Comment: what is the size of resultSIList

Comment: That piece is looping `i` from `offset` to `Math.min(offset + maxItemsInOnePage, totalSIs)-1`. (The initialization is horribly written, but that's what it does as far as I understand.) But how could anyone here know what those variables are? What's `resultSIList`, etc.? You must post the whole relevant code, otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: Also one should not use "l" as a variable name. it looks like 1 and I and makes reading code very difficult.

Comment: @Chin Boon: please write a (j)unit test to help the investigation..

Comment: At first sight, I think totalSIs should set as the size of the list.

Comment: @Chin Boon : I guess now you should able to debug it. See answer from duffymo. (hint. your list is for 15 size.. but iteration goes for more.. ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException would have shown a 'number' in exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected **if and only if** `totalSIs` is equal to or less then the size of the `resultSIList`. Double check that value. Here's a working example with some random values:

```
List<Integer> resultSIList = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
int totalSIs = resultSIList.size();
int maxItemsInOnePage = 2;
int offset = 1;

for (int i = offset, l = Math.min(i + maxItemsInOnePage, totalSIs); i < l; i++){
  resultSIList.get(i);
}
```

---

From you added code I see, that `totalSIs` is bigger (=50) then the list size (=15).

You could add

```
 totalSIs = resultsSIList.size();
```

right behind the for loop for a quick fix.

Comment: Hi Andreas, i think you are right about this. Have you any idea if this is something like a code mistake, or it really is trying to do something?

Comment: It may be doing something reasonable in its context - which I do not know. The code you've shown is a quite complicated way to throw an AIOOBE ;)

Answer (score 2):

This code loops 'resulSIList' from 'offset' position to the minimum of 'offset + maxItemsInOnePage' and 'totalSIs'.

If offset > 0 and totalSIs = resultSIList.size() I think that it won't give you a out of bounds exception.

In your example you have an offset of 50 and the list size it's only 15. You have to check that your offset is less than the list size.

Answer (score 1):

to get some more info you could run it with some logging added:

```
System.out.println("offset: " + offset);
System.out.println("maxItemsInOnePage: " + maxItemsInOnePage);
System.out.println("totalSIs: " + totalSIs);
System.out.println("resultSIList.size(): " + resultSIList.size());
for (int i = offset, l = Math.min(i + maxItemsInOnePage, totalSIs); i < l; i++){
    System.out.println("i: " + i);
    resultSIList.get(i);
}
```

running this should shed some light on your problem; the last i that gets printed was out of bound and by analyzing the four first printouts, you should find your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `offset` is less than the size of your list.

Comment: If `offset` is greater or equal (presumably, `totalSIs`), then the `for` body will not run (due to `i < l`).

Answer (score 0):

You should always check whether your index i is less the size

```
for (int i = offset, l = Math.min(i + maxItemsInOnePage, totalSIs);
      i < l && i < resultSIList.size ();
      i++){
  resultSIList.get(i);
}
```